# Adding unique integers

Tags: python

Write a Python program that reads an integer that gives the number of integers to be read and then reads these integers, one per line, into a list. Print the total of these integers except that if an integer appears more than once it will not be counted.

You may not use the count method of lists. For example, the input:

• 5 1 2 3 4 5 would give 15;

• 5 1 2 3 4 2 would give 8;

• 5 1 2 1 4 2 would give 4; and

• 5 2 2 2 2 2 would give 0.

My code works but is a little hard to read, anyways to so simply this without imports?

```
xs = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))] 
print(sum([xs[i] for i in range(len(xs)) \ if xs[i] not in xs[:i] + xs[i + 1:]]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to simplify a list comprehension that you wrote?

Comment: I am confused by your test cases. Why doesn't  5 2 2 2 2 2 give 5?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Because 5 is the number of 2s

Comment: `for i in range(len(xs)): if xs[i] not in ...` is an anti-pattern in Python. Use `for i,x in enumerate(xs): if x not in ...`

Comment: I'd sort the array and then you can easily iterate through the array to check for duplicates.

Comment: I assume this is homework, and `set`s are either not introduced or verboten?

Answer (score 1):

Split the counting and summing steps.  Do one pass over the list to determine the unique elements, then another to sum them.

```
from collections import Counter

def sum_unique(inputs):
    counts = Counter(inputs)
    return sum(num for num, count in counts.items() if count == 1)

xs = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))] 
print(sum_unique(xs))
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't see "without imports".  You can make a regular `dict` act like a `Counter`, it's just not as pretty.

```
def sum_unique(inputs):
    counts = {}
    for x in inputs:
        counts[x] = counts.get(x, 0) + 1
    return sum(num for num, count in counts.items() if count == 1)
```